# Service mysqld 5.6 keeps starting and stopping on CentOS 6.9

Tags: centos, mysql

On my VPS, mysqld starts and right after that, it automatically stops and then starts again automatically.

I tried `sudo service mysqld stop` and it succeeded. After I started it manually and succeeded. But it suddenly stopped and started and keeping starting and stopping.

Every time I got different PIDs.

How can I fix this?

I started mysqld manually and got these errors:

```
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': signed value 65536 adjusted to 5242880
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 5.0M
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.42 started; log sequence number 4940394469
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@v4452.vir.kagoya.net' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Warning] 'user' entry '@v4452.vir.kagoya.net' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@v4452.vir.kagoya.net' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2018-12-30 16:51:00 4535 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.42'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2018-12-30 16:51:15 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:51:15 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:51:15 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:53:56 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:53:56 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:53:56 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:54:16 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:54:16 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:54:16 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:54:32 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:54:32 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:54:32 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:54:33 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:54:33 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:54:33 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:56:18 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2018-12-30 16:56:18 4535 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

I also did in the MySQL CLI:

```
mysql> use mylife;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    1
```

The mylife DB has InnoDB tables.

Comment: Have you checked the mysql error log to see why it's crashing?

Comment: @jordanm I haven't. So I started mysqld manually and pasted it at https://pastebin.com/c52FxhBZ . And I also posted what I did in MySQL CLI at https://pastebin.com/fYvV86f0 .

Comment: Are those myisam tables?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No, all databases' tables are InnoDB.

Comment: Care to tell us what happened before? I  think you are not telling us the whole story. Restoring a backup?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have no idea why this happened. The other day, I found that I couldn't access my WordPress sites, so I checked if mysqld is running. First thing I tried is using MySQL CLI to log in as root. "SHOW DATABASES;" and "USE mylife;" worked, but "SHOW TABLES;" caused an error which you kindly pasted above. It said "server has gone away," also "Trying to reconnect." I used top command and found mysqld suddenly disappears, but soon after that, it appears again with a different PID. And it repeats.

Answer (score 2):

You have a corrupt table; `innodb_force_recovery` is not meant to be used with the normal MySQL startup,  and `innodb_force_recovery` is set to an invalid value, hence MySQL giving up on running.

From your MySQL logs:

- Your WordPress DB table /mylife/wp_options is marked as corrupted;
- `innodb_force_recovery` is set to an invalid value.

Setting `innodb_force_recovery` to 1 and starting MySQL *might* allow you to repair the table manually; however MySQL is not started normally.

Start with with the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/HOSTNAME.pid --skip-external-locking --port=3306 --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then do:

```
# mysql
> use mylife;
> repair table wp_options;
> exit;
```

Now, **REMOVE** the `innodb_force_recovery` setting. You will be able to restart MySQL afterwards.

For reference, see [mysql Innodb – Table ‘user’ is marked as crashed and should be repaired](http://www.dlaube.com/2011/01/mysql-innodb-table-user-is-marked-as-crashed-and-should-be-repaired/)

On the event MySQL does not manage to recover the table (unlikely), OR you tried to restore the table file manually, you have to restore the table wp_options from a DB dump before MySQL goes up. InnoDB tables are not meant to be restored as individual table files as MyISAM was, it is a common mistake I have seen people doing over and over again.

Relevant logs:

```
InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!  
[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mylife/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Furthermore, if you are using the option `--skip-name-resolve`, you have to do your grants by IP address and not by DNS name, according to following logs. Mind you this is a warning, and might be remnants of a previous setup; however for the lack of a better context on your question, we cannot be sure what to say about it.

```
[Warning] 'user' entry 'root@v4452.vir.kagoya.net' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
[Warning] 'user' entry '@v4452.vir.kagoya.net' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
[Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@v4452.vir.kagoya.net' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
```

As for getting different PIDs, if a service is dying / restarting, it is normal behaviour to get different PIDs into each subsequent run.

Comment: I followed your kind suggestions.
But I couldn't start MySQL. It's impossible to paste the messages here, so I put it at https://pastebin.com/4WnZ2r5q .

Comment: So, it mysql working now?

Comment: No, when tried mysql, I got an error.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: I would restore that table from a backup dump then. Watch out for any new errors

Comment: I have no backup. I know it was my big mistake that I haven't set any regular back up. And I couldn't use mysqldump now.